# Why Nodejs callback() can't access variable outside callback scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, callback

I am fairly new to NodeJS and to JavaScript in general. Here is my script:

```
var fs = require('fs') ;

var temp = "???";

var test = function (){
    fs.readdir("./", function(err,result){
    temp = result;            // i change the temp's value
    console.log("inter result ....."+temp);        //  temp's value changed
    setTimeout(pr,1000,"inter setTimeout: "+temp);  //  temp's value changed 
    });
}

var pr = function (str){
    console.log("Print str: "+ str);
} ;


test();

setTimeout(pr,1000,"Out setTimeout print: "+temp);  //  Why here temp's value not change???
```

How can I change to the var temp’s value outside the callback?

Comment: The `readdir` callback probably executes *after* the `setTimeout` callback...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTimeout(pr,1000,"Out setTimeout print: "+temp);
```

is the same as

```
var str = "Out setTimeout print: " + temp;
setTimeout(pr, 1000, str);
```

At this point of time `temp` still is `"???"`. You have to use

```
setTimeout(function() {
  pr("Out setTimeout print: "+temp);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

What order do the log statements appear in your console?

I'm not into node.js, but I would expect to see the "Out" one before the "inter" ones because I would guess the `fs.readdir()` function is asynchronous and that the callback function that you provide to it will not be executed until after you've already made the call to `setTimeout()` in the last line of your code at which point `temp` has not yet been changed.

That is, the sequence of execution I would expect from your code is:

1. define `fs`
2. define `temp` set to `???`
3. define `test` function
4. define `pr` function
5. call `test()` function
6. within `test()` call the `fs.readdir()` but then return immediately from `test()` without the callback having been executed yet
7. `setTimeout(pr,1000,"Out setTimeout print: "+temp);` (where the value of `temp` at that moment - still "???" - becomes part of the string that setTimeout will pass to `pr` in one second's time)
8. the callback from `fs.readdir()` is executed, and only then does `temp` get changed. The "inter" timeout gets set.

Comment: yes, your analysis is right,   " setTimeout(pr,1000,"Out setTimeout print: "+temp); "  at this memont , temp is "???"    i change it to "setTimeout(function(){setTimeout(goOn,0,"out setTimeout"+temp);},1000);"    got the right result;

Comment: Why are you using the double `setTimeout`? Once you include the anonymous function you should be able to say `setTimeout(function(){goOn("out setTimeout"+temp);},1000);`

Comment: yes， setTiemout include anonymous function is the better way！